# Let $A$ and $B$ be $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrices. If $B$ is positive definite, $A-B$ is positive semi-definite and $|A|=|B|$. prove that $A=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrices.
If $B$ is positive definite, $A-B$ is positive semi-definite and $\det(A)=\det(B)$.
prove that $A=B$.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ b& d \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}p & q\\ q& s \end{bmatrix}$.
By using the fact that $A$ is positive definite if and only if every principal submatrix of $A$ is positive,
$a>0$ and $ad-b^2>0$.
Also, $a-p\geq 0$ and $(a-p)(d-s)-(b-q)^2\geq0$.
Next, $ad-b^2=ps-q^2$.
Here I can prove $A$ is positive definite.
But most important is to prove that $a=p,b=q,d=s$.
Is there any better approach?

Comment: @Casteels I think he means the determinant of $A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* This works for square matrices of arbitrary sizes, not just $2\times2$. Let $X$ be the positive definite square root of $B$. Now consider $A-B=X\left(X^{-1}AX^{-1}-I\right)X$.

Comment: I think i can understand your step. Since $B$ is positive definite, $B$ is invertible and $B=X^2$ for some positive definite matrix $B$. Then we get $A-B=XX^{-1}AX^{-1}X-XX=X(X^{-1}AX^{-1}-I_2)X$. So the next step is to prove $A-B=0$? I have no idea how to apply $\det(A)=\det(B)$ here.

Comment: @AlanWang Try to prove that $X^{-1}AX^{-1}-I$ is positive semidefinite and use the determinant condition as well as the eigenvalues of $C=X^{-1}AX^{-1}$ to conclude that $C=I$

Comment: Up to here I can only prove that $X^{-1}AX^{-1}$ is symmetric and $|C|=1$. Do I need to use any decomposition method or diagonalization in order to find the eigenvalue of $X^{-1}AX^{-1}-I$ and $C$?

Comment: @AlanWang You don't need to calculate the eigenvalues. What are the implications on the eigenvalues of $C$ if $C-I$ is positive semidefinite? How are the eigenvalues of $C$ related to the determinant of $C$?

Comment: I am not sure whether my thought is correct. Note that $C$ is positive definite. Hence $C=P \textrm{diag} (\lambda_1,\lambda_2)P^T$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $C$. Then eigenvalues of $C-I$ will be $\lambda_1-1,\lambda_2-1$. And since $C-I$ is positive semidefinite, $\lambda_1\geq 1,\lambda_2\geq 1$. Also $1=|C|=\lambda_1\lambda_2$. Hence we get $\lambda_1,\lambda_2=1$ and hence $C=I$

Comment: @AlanWang You are almost there, but you need to explain why $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ implies that $C=I$? What properties does your $P$ enjoy?

Comment: Note that $\textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=I$, so we get $C=PP^T$ and since P is orthogonal, $C=PP^T=I$

Comment: Sorry one more question to ask..how to know that $C-I$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @AlanWang If $M$ is positive semidefinite and $P$ is real invertible, then $P^TMP$ is positive semidefinite.